# Activation of vaction option - postfix

Tags: debian, roundcube, postfix

I'm running Postfix 2.7.1 on Debian - I've been wondering how to use the vacation (vacation.pl) program properly?
When I log on as a administrator I get into root where I call the vacation program
(check out the picture)

As I come to understand it hidden file (.forward) is being placed somewhere but I would like to know *how initiate vacation status for a specific account?*

[image: vacation setup process]

The process (in the picture) doesn't make it really easy to understand.

Comment: Where are you get the vacation file (vacation.pl) ?

Comment: as I believe it is a part of postfix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `.forward` file has delivery instructions for the incoming mail. For eg. if john UNIX user receives a mail and he has a .forward file in his home `/home/john/.forward` it will be used to perform the delivery. Consider the following .forward file

```
#John's .forward file
john.gm@gmail.com
|/usr/bin/vacation.pl
```

For the above forward file, the incoming email will be forwarded to john.gm@gmail.com and also sent to the program /usr/bin/vacation.pl More info about how postfix handles `.forward` files herehttp://www.postfix.org/local.8.html

This should help you.

Comment: thx for the answer!